# cheerio помогите спарсить фразу с страницы cloudflare

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

[image: cloudflare]

вот типичная страница с cloudflare
мне надо вытащить любую фразу. 
я нацелился на фразу checking your browser before accessing.
мои попытки

```
$('.cf-browser-verification.cf-im-under-attack span').text()
$('.cf-browser-verification.cf-im-under-attack span').find('checking_browser').text()
$('div').find('checking_browser').text()
```

Comment: `$("span[data-translate="checking_browser"]")`, а так?

Comment: спасибо) работает

Answer (score -1):

Предлагаю вашему вниманию код и библиотеки, которые обходят защиту cloudflare:

Библиотеки:

```
npm i puppeteer-extra puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth puppeteer
```

nodejs:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra')
const pluginStealth = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth')
const { executablePath } = require('puppeteer')

const link = 'https://pegaxy.io/'

const getHtmlThoughCloudflare = async (url) => {
  puppeteer.use(pluginStealth())
  const result = await puppeteer
    .launch({ headless: true })
    .then(async (browser) => {
      const page = await browser.newPage()
      await page.goto(url)
      const html = await page.content()
      await browser.close()
      return html
    })

  console.log(` HTML: ${result}`)
  return result // html
}

getHtmlThoughCloudflare(link)
```